# append list with updated dictionary values

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

I am trying to update list with updated dictionary values for keys. But somehow the list is only taking values from the last iteration.
my code is:

```
dict = {}
list = []
def load(N,P,S):
    dict.update({"number": N, "param" : P, "state": S})
    list.append(dict)


k = 3
for i in range(k):
    num = i
    par = num+1
    state = num *10
    load(num,par,state)

j = 4
for i in range(j):
    num = j*2
    par=j+3
    state=j*12
    load(num,par,state)
    
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep updating and appending the same dict. You should create a new dict in the `load()` function.

```
def load(N,P,S):
    list.append({"number": N, "param" : P, "state": S})
```

P.S. don't name your variables `list` and `dict`. Those are the names of Python built-in functions, and you're replacing those functions.

Comment: Thanks for answer Barmar. But, is there any way possible that I should not put dict{} inside of load function that means I stricty need dict{} to be outside to do some other manipulations as well.

Comment: You don't need the `dict` variable at all, unless it has some other entries that you want to merge with these.